# How do you create a chart in aspx

Tags: c#, charts

I'm trying to create a simple graph in asp.net. I have a SQL query but don't know how to set it to populate a chart. I have a chart defined as ChartDefaultPageOpenTickets. I'd like to set my data set to the chart in order to populate a graph with status on the x axis and total number of open tickets on the y axis.

```
namespace StatusTrackerWeb
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    string query = "";

                    DataTable data = new DataTable();
                    data.Columns.Add("Status");
                    data.Columns.Add("Total");


                    //get a list of all open tickets by status

                    query = "SELECT status, count(ticketnumber) FROM maintable GROUP BY status HAVING status IN ('New','In Progress - Review','In Progress - Scripting','In Progress - Execution','To Be Closed','Waiting- App Team', 'Waiting - Results Review')";

                    DataSet allopenticketdata = br_common_functions.GetDataSet(query);



                }
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
            {
                //dont do anything
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Session["error_string"] = ex.Message;
                Session["stack_trace_string"] = ex.StackTrace.ToString();

                Page.Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
            }   



        }

      }              
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I have a chart defined as ChartDefaultPageOpenTickets", but if you are just looking for a simple way to display a DataSet in an ASP.NET app you may want to look at `System.Web.Helpers.Chart`. Not a lot of bells and whistles, but fairly straightforward.

Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538296%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), and a nice tutorial with samples [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart).